# Joining documents with Raven 2.0 - Could not find index?

Tags: ravendb

I'm new to RavenDB and I have a question about joining two documents with Raven 2.0

I found this page http://daniellang.net/joining-documents-in-ravendb-2-0/ that helped me in finding a solution to join two documents.

Please see my code first (it compiles)

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {DataDirectory = @"C:\temp\ravendata"}.Initialize())
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var products = session.Query<Product, UserProducts>()
                                      .AsProjection<UserProductProjection>()
                                      .ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserProductProjection
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
}

internal class UserProducts : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product, UserProductProjection>
{
    public UserProducts()
    {
        Map = products => from product in products
                          select new
                                 {
                                     UserName = LoadDocument<User>(product.UserId).Name,
                                     ProductName = product.Name,
                                     ProductId = product.Id
                                 };

        Index(projection => projection.ProductId, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(projection => projection.ProductName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Store(projection => projection.UserName, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

```
Raven.Database.Exceptions.IndexDoesNotExistsException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Could not find index named: UserProducts
  Source=Raven.Database
  StackTrace:
       at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass9a.<Query>b__90(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 1100
  ....
```

I really have NO clue at all!! Google doesn't help me on this subject as well, because it is still pretty new as I found out.

If someone has a hint or a solution I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have defined the index you haven't created it in ravendb.

See [Defining a static index](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/defining-static-index?version=2.0) but basically you need....

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(UserProducts).Assembly, documentStore);
```

Comment: Wow! That is pretty simple!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank the ravendb guys,  they are the ones who made it so :)